# Why do my recipes in Minecraft Forge 1.16.5 not work?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have coded recipes and they are not working.

`src/main/resources/data/tme/recipes/roesti_from_crafting.json`:

```
    {
      "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
      "pattern":
      [
        "ppp",
        "ccc",
        "pap"
      ],
      "key":
      {
        "a":
        {
          "tag": "minecraft:coal"
        },
        "p":
        {
          "item": "minecraft:potato"
        },
        "c":
        {
          "item": "tme:cheese"
        }
      },
      "result":
      {
        "item": "tme:roesti",
        "count": 1
      }
    }
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the json with "group": MOD_ID.
EXAMPLE:

```json
{ 
"group": "modid",
"type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
"pattern": [
"AA",
"AS",
" S"
],
"key": {
  "S": {
    "item": "minecraft:stick"
    },
  "A": {
    "item": "modid:cool_ingot"
    }
  },
"result": {
  "item": "modid:cool_axe",
  "count": 1
  }
}
```

I use this template for my recipes.

Also the name for the file is wrong. It should be the same as the item name. so the name for this template file should be /path/to/src/main/resources/data/modid/recipes/cool_axe.json